# How to add ember to a NodeJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I add Ember to an existing NodeJS project without using the `ember-cli` module. Could I simply include `ember.min.js` and `ember-data.min.js` into my rendered .hbs? Secondly, if I am already using Handlebars on NodeJS would this satisfy Ember's dependancy?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ to see how Ember can be started the traditional way, without Ember CLI.

Comment: Thank you, however that is not the **latest** version of Ember and what if my I am using `.hbs`?

Comment: Using Ember 2.4.2 makes no difference.

Comment: As for `.hbs`, make them available as `<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="route/name">` (or `route.name`, I don't remember).

Comment: Ok thanks, but what do you mean.. make them available as?

Comment: You you render them into HTML, wrapping each into a script tag. Please give another look to http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ . Here's an example with latest Ember version: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lihisu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Please note that this approach is strongly discouraged. You should have a really solid reason not to use Ember CLI.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why would this be discouraged?

Comment: Because you fall out of the Ember CLI ecosystem. You can't use addons and you're stuck with bare metal Ember. Might be enough for some minimal use cases, but definitely not worth doing for a full-fledged project.

Comment: Right I see,well that makes more sense now. How on earth has Ghost.org managed to bundle Ember with NodeJS? I will for now leave this unanswered incase someone has another way of achieving. If not you will get the check :)

Comment: You can also upvote regardless of picking the correct answer. Ghost is using Ember CLI: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/package.json#L24